# assign $_session var from object

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli, session-variables

This is a login script I am working on; It uses mysqli (I know it is not as secure as PDO)
After running the MySQL query I am fetch_object().  I am then assinging $_session to hold the user ID and email. $_SESSION['uid'] = $user->ID works but not $_SESSION['uemail'] = $user->email.  Could this be because of email is stored in the object $user?  Do I have to convert it somehow?

email is store ass a varchar(255) in the database ID is a int(11).

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
   while ($user = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $_SESSION['uid'] = $user->ID;
      $_SESSION['uemail'] = $user->email ;
      header("Location: index.php");
      //exit();
   }
}else {
  echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page.";
    //exit();
}
//var_dump(get_object_vars($result));

//$db->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"SELECT ID, email FROM...` - because you need to select the `email` column also.

Comment: Thank you; I am just going to change that to *.

Comment: If you answer the question I will give you credit.

Comment: It has been done, cheers.

Comment: Credit = +1 ? lol no problemo ;) problem's been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not selecting the email column from the database.

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, email FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I feel stupid now. I am just going to change that to *.

Comment: [`Yeah, I said that`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446023/assign-session-var-from-object#comment41534623_26446023) 4 minutes prior.

Answer (score 2):

Comment to answer:

You need to select the column(s) for which you are querying for:

```
SELECT ID, email FROM ...
```

which is why `$_SESSION['uemail'] = $user->email ;` is failing.

Either choose the specific column(s) in question, or a `SELECT *` would also work.

However and it's been said before, that using `*` isn't suggested, therefore select the actual column(s).